# Как лучше: созревает или вызревает?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее написать? Постепенно *созревает* или *вызревает* идея?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать: **постепенно созревает идея**. Это многозначное слово, одним из его  значений является "развившись, сложиться, принять законченную форму".

**ВЫЗРЕТЬ**, -зреет; св. Достичь полной зрелости, спелости; поспеть. Злаки уже вызрели. Яблоки ещё не вызрели. <Вызревать, -ает; нсв. Вызревание, -я; ср.

**СОЗРЕТЬ**,  1. (нсв. также зреть). Стать зрелым, достичь спелости. Плоды, ягоды созрели. Пшеница созрела. Созрели и трескаются семенные коробочки у тополей. 2. Достичь физической или духовной зрелости (о человеке). 3. (нсв. также зреть). **Развившись, сложиться, принять законченную форму.** **Решение созрело. Созрел план**. Талант созрел.

Answer (score 0):

> Постепенно *созревает* или *вызревает* идея?
>
> Как правильнее написать?

**Верны оба варианта.**

Значение 'принимать законченную форму; складываться, определяться'  отмечается в словарях и у глагола ***вызревать***, и у глагола ***созревать***:

> [**вызрева́ть**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/150893/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
>
> <...>
>
> 2. перен.
>
> **Принимать законченную форму.**
>
> 3. перен.
>
> **Складываться, определяться.**

.

> [**созрева́ть**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/247535/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
>
> <...>
>
> 4. перен.
>
> **Развиваясь, принимать законченную форму; складываться, определяться.**

Примеры:

*Сказанное не означает того, что в сознании автора «Слова» не **вызревала идея** усиления центральной власти.* [Юрий Михайлович Лотман "О русской литературе".](https://books.google.ru/books?id=yOwKAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&dq=%22%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMrJu71tLVAhXmQJoKHT8tC1s4KBDoAQg9MAY)

*На смену мечте о «Святой Руси» постепенно **вызревает идея** «Великой России», а в литературе и живописи появляется личностное начало.* [Горинов М.М., Леонов С.В. "История России: учебное пособие".](https://books.google.ru/books?id=QI7wAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK4tS339LVAhWmB5oKHaJ4A144ChDoAQhBMAY)

*Постепенно **созревает идея** создания новой школы русской классической музыки.* [Владимиров Сергей Владимирович "Неформальный путеводитель по музыкальному Петербургу".](https://books.google.ru/books?id=enE7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG4p_I4dLVAhXJE5oKHTV4B2AQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&f=false)

Следует отметить, что в сочетании с ***постепенно*** и ***идеей*** в книгах **чаще** встречается глагол ***вызревает***.

Ср.:

***["постепенно вызревает идея"](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=825&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&oq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...66820.70196.0.73117.4.4.0.0.0.0.67.254.4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.cvsCMCQ__Zo) — ["постепенно созревает идея"](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%22&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibnL6z2dLVAhWKJZoKHX6NAmYQBQgkKAA&biw=1280&bih=825&dpr=1)***